# Countdown timer - want to achieve completion notification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a countdown timer for the scheduled event. Every thing is ok but unable to get the completion time notification. I mean when the timer is completed it should have some custom HTML instead timer like **'Event is started'** etc..

can you anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

here is the code and fiddle URL I am trying with:

http://jsfiddle.net/r3EtY/1/

```
var target_date = new Date("Jan 30, 2014").getTime();

var days, hours, minutes;
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
setInterval(function () {
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600 + 14);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    countdown.innerHTML = days + "<span> Day(s)</span>, " + hours + "<span> Hour(s)</span>, "
    + minutes + "<span> Min(s)</span>";  

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to check the time left. If `days`, `hours`, `minutes` and `second` are all `0`.

```
var countdownLoop = setInterval(function () {

    // your calculation here

    if (seconds < 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownLoop);
        countdown.innerHTML = "Event started!";
    } else {
        countdown.innerHTML = days + "<span> Day(s)</span>, " + hours + "<span> Hour(s)</span>, " + minutes + "<span> Min(s)</span>";  
    }

}, 1000);
```

And the `clearInterval(countdownLoop);` stops the loop since it's no longer needed.

Comment: It should have been `second <= 0`, I fixed my answer

Comment: There was a typo, it's `seconds`, not `second`. My bad. http://jsfiddle.net/r3EtY/13/

Comment: Its been more than a week and I am done with it.... but I really appreciate your answer... this is what I wanted. thanks a lot for efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition to clear the Interval and show other text:

```
if (seconds_left <= 0) { clearInterval(0); }
countdown.innerHTML = 
  seconds_left <= 0  ? "done!" 
                     : days + "<span> Day(s)</span>, " + hours + 
                       "<span> Hour(s)</span>, " +
                       + minutes + "<span> Min(s)</span>"
```

But not all is well with your code.<sup>**1**</sup> Feel free to use and fiddle around with [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/yMt5w/) <sup>**2**</sup>

<sup>**1**</sup> try running it using

```
var target_date = new Date; 
target_date.setSeconds(target_date.getSeconds()+5);
```

It shows a remaining time of `0 Day(s), 14 Hour(s), 0 Second(s)`

<sup>**2**</sup> To run with your date value, change code lines

```
timeouttime = new Date('2014/01/30').getTime(),
// and after initialize
d.querySelector('#timeout').value = 
   Math.floor( ( timeouttime - new Date().getTime()  ) / 1000 );
doSet();
btn.click();
```

Here's a [**fork**](http://jsfiddle.net/94ynP/) of the initial jsFiddle

Comment: way around but works well.. how about without click and input the date and time already.. thanksssss

Comment: See edited answer. I don't have time to do more coding for you. Take the jsFiddle and fiddle! Also check the code @ http://testbed.nicon.nl/timing/timer.html

Answer (score 0):

var target_date = new Date("Jan 28, 2014").getTime();
    var days, hours, minutes;
    var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

```
var interv = setInterval(function () {
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600 + 14);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

countdown.innerHTML = days + "<span> Day(s)</span>, " + hours + "<span> Hour(s)</span>, " + minutes + "<span> Min(s)</span>";


if ((seconds + minutes + hours + days) <= 0) {
    clearInterval(interv);
    myFunc();
}

}, 1000);

function myFunc() {
//code
}
```

[Demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkumar670/GbB8j/4/)

Thanks,